# Created an object of arrays from a for loop

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I wrote the code below to try and pull the time from the ScheduledArrivalTime field from the data in the obj variable. I wanted to try and push this extracted time data into a new array so it can be used in a different function later on.

At the moment it's outputting the time to my array as

```
05, 29, 00,05, 35, 00
```

but I want to get it in the form of

```
[{05, 29, 00}, {05, 35, 00}]
```

or

```
[{
    "time": [05, 29, 00]
}, {
    "time": [05, 35, 00]
}]
```

here is the code I've got at the moment. When I try and do t.push({}), all the code outputs is [object,Object]. I don't know where I'm going wrong

```js
var headings, obj, i, x = "";
obj = {
    "data": [{
        "Site": "RTL",
        "Operator": "RGB",
        "LineRef": "53a",
        "ScheduledArrivalTime": "2018-08-07 05:29:00",
        "EndPoint":"Madejski Stadium"
    }, {
        "Site": "RTL",
        "Operator": "RGB",
        "LineRef": "53a",
        "ScheduledArrivalTime": "2018-08-07 05:35:00",
        "EndPoint":"Madejski Stadium"
    }]
}


var t = [];
for (i in obj.data) {
    var time = obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[11] + obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[12] + ", " +  obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[14] + obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[15] + ", " +      obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[17] + obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[18];

 t.push(time);
}

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = t;
```

```html
<br>
<p id="time"></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if you want to write in the `innerHTML` the exact structure as you see in `console.log` for example, you will need to concat some characters to show up.

As you can see, console.log shows exactly what you need, here in my code, but to show in the document, I needed to use a "hacky" way to show.

> When I try and do t.push({}), all the code outputs is [object,Object].

When you say that, is because when you simply try to add the entire object at once to the document, it uses the `toString()` of the object, that's why it shows `[Object object]`, it is the expected behavior.

Please, see if this helps you, if not, please tell me why.

```js
var headings, obj, i, x = "";
obj = {
    "data": [{
        "Site": "RTL",
        "Operator": "RGB",
        "LineRef": "53a",
        "ScheduledArrivalTime": "2018-08-07 05:29:00",
        "EndPoint":"Madejski Stadium"
    }, {
        "Site": "RTL",
        "Operator": "RGB",
        "LineRef": "53a",
        "ScheduledArrivalTime": "2018-08-07 05:35:00",
        "EndPoint":"Madejski Stadium"
    }]
}

var t = [];
for (i in obj.data) {
  var time = obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[11] + obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[12] + ", " +  obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[14] + obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[15] + ", " +      obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[17] + obj.data[i].ScheduledArrivalTime[18];
    
  let timeObj = {time} // <-- The Object you want is here.
  t.push(timeObj); 
}

console.log(t)
var myElem = document.getElementById("time")

//To show in the document exactly as an Array of objects structure:
myElem.innerHTML = "["

for (var i = 0; i < t.length; i++){
  myElem.innerHTML += "{" + t[i].time + "}"; 
  if (typeof t[i+1] != 'undefined'){
      myElem.innerHTML += ", "; 
  }
}

myElem.innerHTML += "]"
```

```html
<p id="time"></p>
```

Comment: that worked thank you! I used a different editor and could see what you meant regarding the output in the console. I was able to use the data even when it didn't show in the document. I thought as it didn't show in the document, something had gone wrong. I need to watch the console more..

Comment: Yes, a good developer is ways up to console and Dev tools. ;)

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest not to use index based hours/minutes/seconds retrieving, but rather create a `Date` object from the string and then afterwards get all the required information from it.

You can use code below as an example of building a structure, which has hours/minutes/seconds inside, so that they are afterwards used to format the output string.

```
var headings, obj, i, x = "";
obj = {
    "data": [{
        "Site": "RTL",
        "Operator": "RGB",
        "LineRef": "53a",
        "ScheduledArrivalTime": "2018-08-07 05:29:00",
        "EndPoint":"Madejski Stadium"
    }, {
        "Site": "RTL",
        "Operator": "RGB",
        "LineRef": "53a",
        "ScheduledArrivalTime": "2018-08-07 05:35:00",
        "EndPoint":"Madejski Stadium"
    }]
}

const retrieveScheduledArrivalTime = (data) => {
    return data.map((entry) => {
    const date = new Date(entry.ScheduledArrivalTime);
    const hours = date.getHours();
    const minutes = date.getMinutes();
    const seconds = date.getSeconds();
    return {
        hours,
      minutes,
      seconds
    };
    });
}

const getScheduledArrivalTimeAsText = (time) => {
    return time.hours + ':' + time.minutes + ':' + time.seconds;
};

const t = retrieveScheduledArrivalTime(obj.data);

document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = t.map(getScheduledArrivalTimeAsText).join('<br/>');
```

Comment: this works really well for displaying the times on the document - thank you! Although I am struggling to then use the times in a later function by separating out the hour, minutes and seconds.

Comment: can you please elaborate a bit more on what information you need in later functions?

Comment: i need the time that has been pulled from the data to find the difference between that value and the current time. The way I've written this in my script is by separating out the hour, minute and second values and then finding the difference between each separately. I understand this is a really long way of doing this, but it's working

Comment: Actually what you can do, when you have 2 `Date` object, you can subtract one from the other and it will return your the amount of milliseconds, which in the end can be converted to hours/mins/seconds. Or you can use this library moment.js